# I want to know whether there is an concept of z index in unity 5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to know whether there is an concept of `z index` in `unity 5` (`GridLayout` is setting `z index` automatically how to set the active grid on top of all).

Comment: Unity 4.6 + uses child index of transform to draw things in order. You cannot override it but you can simply move the ui element to the last sibiling position and it will be drawn on top. Edit, well you can with custom shader, but then things will go messy.